Firebase Firestore Not Allowing Authenticated User
I'm struggling with this
I have a project and i'm struggling with getting data from the database from an authenticated user. I feel like I'm missing something.
In firebase.js I have
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const firestore = getFirestore(app);

// Initialize Authentication
const auth = getAuth(app);
setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("User Persistence is Local");

  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error setting persistence:', error);
  });
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      // User is signed in
      console.log("User is signed in:", user);
    } else {
      // User is signed out
      console.log("User is signed out");
    }
  });

I can sign-up and log-in then when I try to load something in
src/app/home/page.jsx
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { auth,firestore } from '../../../../firebase';
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import createNewProject from '../../api/makeNewProject'
const Page = () => {

  const fetchData = async () => {
    console.log("current user:",auth.currentUser)
    const dataRef = collection(firestore, 'data');
    console.log("data ref",dataRef)
  return (
<div/>)};

Logs value
current user: null
dataref: null
current user: null
dataref: null
User is signed in: {userID}
User Persistence is Local

Intuitively this should initialize firebase when I start the dev server or on import -> set persistence -> check/set user auth -> try to pull data from firestore
rules for debugging are
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow any authenticated user to read and write to the projects collection
    match /data/{dataId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    // Allow any authenticated user to read and write to the users collection
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}


Users are not considered fully signed in until after the onAuthStateChanged callback is invoked.  It won't be invoked immediately when the page loads - it takes time time to load and validate the token.  Your component will need to wait until that callback says a user is signed in before make the query that requires authentication.

Based on the comment above I created a function
  const waitForAuth = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log("User is signed in");
        resolve(user);
      } else {
        console.log("User is signed out");
        reject(new Error('User is not signed in'));
      }
    });
  });

Then called this throughout the project
const fetchProjects = async () => {
    await waitForAuth;
    const dataRef = collection(firestore, 'data');

